# XMPP frameworks

Tags: ios7, xcode5, xmppframework

`.h` and `.m` files of the *xmpp*, I am trying work on a chat application.
But when i build the project I get the following error, I am trying to solve the problem from past 24 hours, but was not successful to get the solution, I even googled but didn't got the solution. 
The following is the error which i am getting,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_dns_free_resource_record", referenced from:
      -[XMPPSRVResolver processRecord:length:] in XMPPSRVResolver.o
  "_dns_parse_resource_record", referenced from:
      -[XMPPSRVResolver processRecord:length:] in XMPPSRVResolver.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Seems that you need to add `libresolv.dylib` to your frameworks (step 6 here: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS)

Comment: Thanks @Larme, the problem has been solved. i just added the libresolv.dylib as u mentioned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to add `libresolv.dylib` to your frameworks.
In [this tutorial](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS), it's step 6:

> Step 6
>
> Add the following folders to your project, and add to your Xcode
>   project:
>
> Authentication Categories Core Utilities In addition, add
>   libresolv.dylib to your Xcode project. (In Xcode 4, go to Target ->
>   Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> + -> Select
>   libresolv.dylib from drop down list)
>
> Ensure your project compiles.
>
> And now you're ready to start using XMPPFramework in your project. The
>   Intro to XMPPFramework page explains how to do this.

Comment: from where i download libresolv.dylib  ?